# CyanogenMod logo loop

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, boot-loop, twrp

My mobile, HTC One X was on CyanogenMod 10.1 which received a update **cm-10.1-20130304-EXPERIMENTAL**. Once the update package download is completed, I tried to update it via update settings but it restarted on recovery mode and restarted without being updated.

So, I installed the update package via TRWP and once the update installation is completed, the phone restarted and the cyanogenMod logo is on loop.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleared dalvik cache and it worked.

Comment: For some phones this can also be due to an outdated boot.img, I seem to remember that I once had to flash it manually via ADB (although it should be flashed with the ZIP from CWM recovery) and that made the bootloop go away.